# Let Javascript check which Button was pressed and change specific HTML details with it

Tags: javascript, html

on my Website I've got a few buttons which shall open or close specific HTML details. 
My Buttons (i've got way more):

```
 <button onClick="showdetail()" class="stage-detail">1</button>
 <button onClick="showdetail()" class="stage-detail">2</button>
```

My Details (some more aswell):

```
<details id="brock1"></details>
<details id="brock2"></details>
```

Now I want to write a Javascript that detects which button was pressed and than opens or closes the right details.
For example: 
If button1 was pressed: details "brock1" shall be open, and details "brock2" shall be closed.
With button2 the direct opposite.

I started like this:

```
var i;
var detail = document.getElementsByClassName("stage-detail");

    for (i = 0; i < detail.length; i++){
        detail[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

        }
    }
```

and now I stuck..
I mean I could write seperate functions for each button but that sounds dumb to me because they would do pretty much the same.
Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Does any of the answers (besides my [own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53825769/2813224)) actually open and close any `<details>s` tags?

Comment: Yes, holydragon's opened 1, but both buttons opened the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use an Unlimited Number of `<button>s` to an Equal Amount of `<details>`

### [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

Handle an **unlimited number** of `<button>s` with a **single [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)**:

1. If you don't have a tag wrapped around the `<button>s`, make it so. (`section.buttons`).
2. Register the `click` event to the parent tag of the `<button>s` (`section.buttons`).
3. Have the callback function (`toggleDetails()`) use the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) (the clicked `<button>`) property to determine which `<button>` was clicked by comparing it to the [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) (the tag registered to the click event -- `section.buttons`).

---

### [[open] Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) `<details open>`

`<details>` have an attribute called `[open]` that when `true` (or just there) -- `<details>` is open and when `false` (or just not there), `<details>` is closed.

---

> *"How can I use something different than the textContent for the num variable?"*

The `<button>s` can be collected then indexed, see updated **Demo 2**.

### Demo 1

**Details are commented in demo.**

```js
// Reference the parent tag of <button>s
var btns = document.querySelector('.buttons');

// Register parent tag of <button>s to the click event
btns.addEventListener('click', toggleDetails);

// Callback function passes Event Object (e)
function toggleDetails(e) {
  // Reference clicked tag (ie <button>)
  var tgt = e.target;
  /*
  if clicked tag is NOT the registered tag (ie section.buttons)...
  ...get the text of clicked <button> (ie a number)...
  ...then reference the tag with the #id of "brock"+a number which
  will end up to be a <details> tag.
  if this <details> tag has an [open] attribute...
  ...remove it...
  otherwise...
  ...add it and set it to true.
  */
  if (tgt !== e.currentTarget) {
    var num = tgt.textContent;
    var dtl = document.getElementById('brock' + num);
    if (dtl.getAttribute('open')) {
      dtl.removeAttribute('open');
    } else {
      dtl.setAttribute('open', true);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Wrap <button>s in a tag-->
<section class='buttons'>
  <button class="stage-detail">1</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">2</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">3</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">4</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">5</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">6</button>
</section>

<details id="brock1">ONE</details>
<details id="brock2">TWO</details>
<details id="brock3">THREE</details>
<details id="brock4">FOUR</details>
<details id="brock5">FIVE</details>
<details id="brock6">SIX</details>
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
// Reference the parent tag of <button>s
var stage = document.querySelector('.stage');

// Register parent tag of <button>s to the click event
stage.addEventListener('click', toggleDetails);

// Callback function passes Event Object (e)
function toggleDetails(e) {
  // Reference clicked tag (ie <button>)
  var tgt = e.target;
  // Collect all <button>s into a NodeList
  var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  // Declare variable
  var num;
  /*
  On each loop through NodeList...
  if there's a clicked <button>...
  ...assign the index number +1 to previous variable (num).
  */
  for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    if (btns[i] === tgt) {
      num = i + 1;
    }
  }
  /*
  if clicked tag is NOT the registered tag (ie section.buttons)...
  ...then reference the tag with the #id of "brock"+a number which
  will end up to be a <details> tag.
  if this <details> tag has an [open] attribute...
  ...remove it...
  otherwise...
  ...add it and set it to true.
  */
  if (tgt !== e.currentTarget) {
    var dtl = document.getElementById('brock' + num);
    if (dtl.getAttribute('open')) {
      dtl.removeAttribute('open');
    } else {
      dtl.setAttribute('open', true);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Wrap <button>s in a tag-->
<section class='stage'>
  <button class="stage-detail">1</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">2</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">3</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">4</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">5</button>
  <button class="stage-detail">6</button>
</section>

<details id="brock1">ONE</details>
<details id="brock2">TWO</details>
<details id="brock3">THREE</details>
<details id="brock4">FOUR</details>
<details id="brock5">FIVE</details>
<details id="brock6">SIX</details>
```

Comment: How can I use something different than the textContent for the num variable?

Comment: @DieneMutter see **Demo 2**

Answer (score 1):

can you try this:

```
<button onClick="showdetail(1)" class="stage-detail">1</button>
<button onClick="showdetail(2)" class="stage-detail">2</button>

<script>
    function showdetail(btnnumber){
       console.log('you pressed the button: ' + btnnumber);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can I use the btnnumber in if(btnumber= 1) ?

Comment: @DieneMutter Do you have any idea how to actually open `<details>`? See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53825769/2813224).

Answer (score 0):

How about you make `showdetail()` take 1 input which determines the button clicked?

And use it like this.

```
<button onClick="showdetail(1)" class="stage-detail">1</button>
<button onClick="showdetail(2)" class="stage-detail">2</button>
```

Now in your function, you know exactly which button is clicked by looking at the input. The rest is mapping and toggling.

Comment: How can I access those inputs?

Comment: Your function may look something like var showdetail = function(buttonId){ console.log(buttonId); }

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<button onClick="showdetail('brock1')" class="stage-detail">1</button>
<button onClick="showdetail('brock2')" class="stage-detail">2</button>


<details id="brock1"></details>
<details id="brock2"></details>
```

.

```
<script>
    function showdetail(id){
        let the_selected_element = document.getElementById(id);

        //do something with the selected element
        alert(the_selected_element.innerHTML);
    }
</script>
```